# HTML Multiple DIVs using same style and script functions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not a especialist in html and I'd like to show some DIVs as Popups, each one with their own ID,but with the same styles and functions to drag, hide and show. Below is the way I wrote for 2 of then, it's working for 2 popups.

As you can see, it's a copy of style and functions, I'd like that to be a lot of divs with one style source and funtions

I know it's horrible, that's why I need some help. Best Regards

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id="mydiv">
<style>
#mydiv {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 9;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    }
    #mydivheader {
      padding: 10px;
      cursor: move;
      z-index: 10;
      background-color: #2196F3;
      color: #fff;
    }
</style>
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
  <button onclick= "hideElement()">close</button>
  <script>
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));
function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }
  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }
  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }
  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
function hideElement() {
        element = document.getElementById("mydiv");
         element.style.display = "none";
}
</script>   
</div>

<div id="mydiv1">
<style>
    #mydiv1 {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 9;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    }
    #mydivheader1 {
      padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
  <div id="mydivheader1">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
  <button onclick= "hideElement1()">close</button>
  <script>
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv1"));
function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header1")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header1").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }
  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }
  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
function hideElement1() {
        element = document.getElementById("mydiv1");
         element.style.display = "none";
     }
</script>   
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use classes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) in your CSS for shared styles properties between your divs.

For example regroup :

```
 #mydiv1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
```

and

```
 #mydiv1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
```

In a class like this :

```
 .nice-modal {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
```

For your javascript, you should use indexes in argument for your functions, that target a specific id using the index given in parameters such as :

```
function hideElement1() {
        element = document.getElementById("mydiv1");
         element.style.display = "none";
     }
```

Become :

```
function hideElement(index) {
        element = document.getElementById("mydiv" + index);
         element.style.display = "none";
     }
```

This should help you figure the rest by yourself !

Comment: Hi, I recommend you link to a better site than W3Schools; they're known for inaccurate and outdated content (and sketchy business practices). Linking to a site like MDN or even the actual W3C spec would be better.

Comment: @TylerH thanks for the input, I edit my answer right now !

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the below code, it's the same code as your's but there was a open style tag in line:3 and the div with id "mydiv" at line:4 does not have a closing tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#mydiv {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 9;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    }
    #mydivheader {
      padding: 10px;
      cursor: move;
      z-index: 10;
      background-color: #2196F3;
      color: #fff;
    }
</style>
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
  <button onclick= "hideElement()">close</button>
  </div>
  <script>
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));
function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }
  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }
  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }
  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
function hideElement() {
        element = document.getElementById("mydiv");
         element.style.display = "none";
}
</script>   
</div>

<div id="mydiv1">
<style>
    #mydiv1 {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 9;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    }
    #mydivheader1 {
      padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
  <div id="mydivheader1">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
  <button onclick= "hideElement1()">close</button>
  <script>
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv1"));
function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header1")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header1").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }
  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }
  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
function hideElement1() {
        element = document.getElementById("mydiv1");
         element.style.display = "none";
     }
</script>   
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide further explanation and good practice (css class usage), this answer doesn't really help author to solve the problem if it ever happens again.